# The specified child already has a parent Android

Tags: android

//EventHome.java

```
public class EventHome extends Activity
{
boolean connected = false;
TextView tv1,tv3,tv4,tv5;
ImageView iv3,iv4,iv7;
String image1,phone;
final Context context=this;
JSONObject event_all;
ArrayList<String> actorsList;
String KEY_LOGIN_NAME = "LoginStatus";
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static final int MENU_ABOUT = Menu.FIRST;
public static final int MENU_PROFILE = Menu.FIRST + 1;
public static final int MENU_PREFERENCES = Menu.FIRST + 2;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private static String PROFILE_URL;
JSONObject event;
GridView gv1;
ScrollView sc;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_home);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
    phone=preferences.getString(KEY_LOGIN_NAME, "");

    tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    iv4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    iv3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv7=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);

    gv1=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    sc=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);

    gv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sc.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            int action = arg1.getActionMasked();

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    sc.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    iv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });

    HttpGetter get = new HttpGetter();
    try {
        String url = "http://www.example.com/check_status_android.php?status=1&pin="+phone;
        get.execute(new URI(url));
        Log.e("*****************", url);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new LoadProfile().execute();

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vf);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // execute AsyncTask
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    // handler to set duration and to upate animation
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AnimateandSlideShow();
        }
    };

    int delay = 500;
    int period = 4000;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
        }
    }, delay, period);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    HttpGetter get = new HttpGetter();
    try {
        String url = "http://www.happwall.com/check_status_android.php?status=0&pin="+phone;
        get.execute(new URI(url));
        Log.e("*****************", url);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE,MENU_ABOUT,Menu.NONE,"about");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,MENU_PROFILE,Menu.NONE,"profile");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE,MENU_PREFERENCES,Menu.NONE,"preferences");

    // Return true so that the menu gets displayed.
    return true;
}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Close the menu after a period of time.
    // Note that this STARTS the timer when the options menu is being
    // prepared, NOT when the menu is made visible.
    Timer timing = new Timer();
    timing.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            closeOptionsMenu();
        }
    }, 10000);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_ABOUT:
            // do whatever
            Intent i=new Intent(EventHome.this,About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case MENU_PROFILE:
            // do whatever
            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_NAME, phone);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i1=new Intent(EventHome.this,Profile.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            return true;
        case MENU_PREFERENCES:
            // do whatever
            editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_NAME, phone);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i2=new Intent(EventHome.this,PreferenceSet.class);
            startActivity(i2);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void moreEvent(View v){
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_NAME, phone);
    editor.commit();

    Intent i=new Intent(this,EventCategory.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void chatNow(View v){
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_LOGIN_NAME, phone);
    editor.commit();

    Intent i=new Intent(EventHome.this,EventChat.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

class HttpGetter extends AsyncTask<URI, Void, Void> 
{
     String response_string = "";
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(URI... urls) 
     {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
             HttpPost httpGet = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
             try {
                     HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                     StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                     int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                     if (statusCode == 200) {
                             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                             InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                             new InputStreamReader(content));
                             String line;
                             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                     builder.append(line);
                             }
                             response_string = builder.toString();
                             Log.v("Getter", "Your data: " + builder.toString()); //response data
                     } else {
                             Log.e("Getter", "Failed to download file");
                     }
             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
             }

             return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(response_string.contains("success"))
        {
            //do your stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do your stuff
        }
     }
}

class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventHome.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json = null;
        PROFILE_URL = "http://www.happwall.com/filter_event_android.php?pin="+phone;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("All Events: ", json.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try{
            event = new JSONObject(json);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONArray user = event.getJSONArray("events");
        String contains=json.toString();

        if(contains.contains("id"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = user.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id", object.getString("id"));
                map.put("name", object.getString("name"));
                map.put("date_d", object.getString("date_d"));
                map.put("location", object.getString("location"));
                map.put("images", "http://www.happwall.com/"+object.getString("images"));
                arraylist.add(map);    
            }

            String[] from = {"name", "date_d", "location", "images"};
            int[] to = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3,  R.id.iv_flag};

            ListAdapter adapters = new MyAdapter(EventHome.this,arraylist,R.layout.list_event_home,from,to);
            gv1.setAdapter(adapters);
        }
        else
        {
            gv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TextView dynamicTextView = new TextView(EventHome.this);
            dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            dynamicTextView.setText("No events available");
        }

        gv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(EventHome.this,EventSingle.class);
                i.putExtra("event_id", arraylist.get(arg2).get("id"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

// AsyncTask to get data from server
  class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {

        //------------------>>
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (status == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

              //  Actors actor = new Actors();
                actorsList.add(object.getString("image"));
             //   actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                Log.d("image: ", object.getString("image"));

             //   actorsList.add(actor);

            }
            return true;
        }

        //------------------>>

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(result == false){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
    else{
        setFlipperImage( actorsList);
       }
    }
  }
  private void setFlipperImage(ArrayList<String> actorsList) {

 for(int i=0;i<actorsList.size();i++){
 Log.i("Set Filpper Called", actorsList.get(i).toString()+"");
 //ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
// image.setBackgroundResource(res);
Picasso.with(EventHome.this)
.load(actorsList.get(i).toString())
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.into(iv7);
 viewFlipper.addView(iv7);
 }
}
// method to show slide show
 private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
 viewFlipper.showNext();
 }

}
```

//event_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:gravity="bottom" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.91"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:onClick="moreEvent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/book"
            android:onClick="chatNow" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ViewFlipper 
    android:id="@+id/vf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Venue, Date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/demo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Event of the Week" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:text="Event Name" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollview"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Today&apos;s Events" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//My Logcat

```
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3344)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3215)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.addView(ViewAnimator.java:182)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3172)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3152)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.event.EventHome.setFlipperImage(EventHome.java:506)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.event.EventHome.access$4(EventHome.java:495)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.event.EventHome$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(EventHome.java:491)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.event.EventHome$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(EventHome.java:1)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-16 15:09:17.417: E/AndroidRuntime(2429):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

while running the above code i got an error 
"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first". What is the reason and how to solve this error. And don't have any idea. I am stuck in here.

Comment: @MrSmith :- Please check the question, i have added the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is precisely what the error message says: You cannot add a child to a ViewGroup, which already belongs to another ViewGroup.

iv7 belongs to your main view:

```
iv7=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
```

Then you add it to the viewFlipper:

```
viewFlipper.addView(iv7);
```

You need to create (or inflate) a new instance of your ImageView, which does not belong to a parent view (ViewGroup).

---

To inflate a view:

Create a separate layout file, which only contains the ImageView you need.
Get a LayoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_id, parentView, false);
```

context is either your activity or can be obtained by `View.getContext()`.

parentView is your viewFlipper.

Comment: how to inflate. I have no idea.

Comment: Instead of addView can we use another method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:-

viewFlipper.addView(iv7);

The mistake that you are doing is that u are adding the same view "iv7" which has already been added to to the relative layout using xml... so to be precise. u cannot add a view which is already added in some layout.

Comment: Then what is the solution. Any method.